# Using a port expander AND other GPIO pins

Tags: pi-3, gpio, rpi.gpio

I'm working with a [port expander](https://www.adafruit.com/product/732) for the pi to run four stepper motors from python. It was working great until I tried to also use a GPIO pin on the pi (not on the port expander) as an output. I was using the RPi library to control pin 22 on the pi, and this seems to have caused the smbus library, which I was using to control the port expander, to throw an input/output error (Error number 5). The program sometimes works fine even with the GPIO pin enabled, but it will randomly throw the error and the stepper motors will not move. I'm still not entirely sure as to the cause of the problem, but it seems like the RPi library is fighting with the smbus library for control over the pins. Is it possible that this is the problem? I'm going to need to control all GPIO pins on the pi plus the port expander. Is there a recommended way to do this without provoking this issue?

Comment: What port expander are you using?

Comment: Here it is: https://www.adafruit.com/product/732

Comment: You can safely use all other GPIO but those in use for I2C (SDA/SCL).  You have done something else wrong.  Without clear photos of your wiring and software listings it is pointless speculating.

Comment: Possible mix up between BCM and board pin numbers?

Comment: Nope, GPIO pin is working as expected

Comment: Ah, I/O Error 5 is related to MCP23017. The following might help. (1) I you have multiple I2C devices of the bus, remove all the devices' on board pullups (usually smd 4k7. or 10k). Rpi's 1k8 pullup won't like other pullups to help. (2) Shorten I2C wiring, to avoid noise picking up from your GPIO related circuit, (3) Lower smbus clock (not for Rpi3B+) from 100k to perhaps 50k or even 10k. This Q&A might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325351/ioerror-errno-5-input-output-error-while-using-smbus-for-analog-reading-thr. Cheers.